# PGP public key flagged as malicious to root. Was ran before

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, homomorphic-encryption, gpg4win

Hello I had used this pgp public key on my win10 OS with pgptool to message someone.

Then when i used that same public key in whonix OS console it came back with some type of warning about malicious item that could go into root?
SO i didnt use it and have been trying to find out what it was, if im infected or what.  I can go back and try and enter pgp to get exact warning if needed.

I added the pgp public key and a "dump" i got from an online scanner. Is there a way to read what files may have been added, modified, etc?

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG v1.63
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=c3Gi
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

Key ID: 25e3b7a45660875
   Algorithm: RSA_GENERAL
   Fingerprint: aeaf4842c344973a0b00356a025e3b7a45660875
   Encoded: 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
   Creation Time: Sun Apr 07 19:19:25 UTC 2019
   Bit Strength: 4096
   Has Revocation: false
   Has EncryptionKey: true
   Has MasterKey: true
   UserId: winamax <trusteelucky@mail2tor>
Key ID: e53a4754fcac61d7 (subkey)
   Algorithm: RSA_GENERAL
   Fingerprint: 5e0e510e2cacd334323eee75e53a4754fcac61d7
   Encoded: b9020d045caa4d3d011000b60fc66b494befe323358dd44b08453a7add30af0d98336627a678a7efd7cf3dbe7e21558e03edbd624bd450fef419e13315732e55e69aa49d47e1c5633425d3d4dbeb2298d1094c25e741dfb0ff534c8b484dd27fe5c82c28d151eac10adc51b7d11db6c7dd08327d1eeba13f078710e74a069df7663187f5c02c9e486ae7e89057801bb39e9abcd6d73b8feb33e3ee8e2ca3a3a73eb8a72546c64c016dd62aa3440a2a0b5880b49f6d39c0fe8bfe9c162a01a25f6231a88c95ed60870ab719eec4e4b4b7ac3a8ccb8fa9a4a95d328c7c3a83d745845cae1bf484b3f3cb4c92b00d8cf794b38cf3718a6b4d76867d9a626d63030d3b66d6fe6c40824b6b7c403bd8c54650613d91b575a8cfdd3d7feffb5a2bb025a0c404970176139c3b27e8530e5f62e2a0f3579dbd830841128244453e994bf873f0bc85a011afa4fecf4b9e24b38e6de6d0444eedfd2c035d5ab2b34ee710e307493de5b8f8e18851c322a1055f4dd0749d49d2e24f2a70bf8682da26a32209fe2ba643e24a6f471f2a1fdf94db27c78310c4f17203d76cb868db886649ddfe4a9021040a010cd6c9cb4343287ad73111882bbec389cfe331e5a855dc0f71655a2a5a4bcaf2a6e985d0d388412d7c53ef459b70791cccdfd5c25a2395aafdc9f5698642959f69b104a425f9396380e64e1a54dfe97db2b1f9e16fbd7f0bd0054de00fd9b6e2cf23026b89001101000189023c041801080026162104aeaf4842c344973a0b00356a025e3b7a4566087505025caa4d3d021b0c050907861f80000a0910025e3b7a456608757b970ffe372664d9c4d00194bd31ea34653d4b8e66dfc9e8a22588799a43cc9c2e848da14be426478f06a9dcc8d695ea01e21f0d34a138a2c3af84fcbaae9187c6131618f5e045599fd4ef9b2f4e76aaa917cade1be7143fa9768a6f4195dc3def773aa1e74bf655767f2854bbfb09efa5d015c2a887ba2b0b33bc778449b06803ea07a9c52c618ac84dd00acc32c1420b3f900f55ff557edd1fc2d98f1fca2526f2a2319ac06ea427838be8de1fe78df538de331c6a1e9be68c488db60594fbdc750ff91bd2d0fea30d82254af94a3d8a4b0ce27c88b885df47a7c2955430bbf9bedea19a0977b7c7c960db9830c8d259e9628a3173e28200bda45145090c0d03f0ed2cb04f0ee91993e27eb128000a67d34fc7078fbfcf7ab6ac887bcf4c5504a31ce8a30b5fad8269b586d180af5cf9248bd0a73b9b67df7f364aa03827b626eea4db8c150bff3a6709cfd73094ac97c31592d9c71d0cb3e0011ea2e23aa3d8cc61cdafebdfcdb74eff5e7621fe5b86ca7b7d0b9c4db47598ee4059ee729254454e5d37cc436c9b95cf27101deb7ac461b58819173065f3927456021fac7d3a49220e224aa938a0dd8135ec5805359783eeada58ed15e115122421c8de52de7e9dd52ecfb76c8d23f0f8c1d80c4e0c0fb55573a07ac93702949816a918cae5fd2ea1c48b2990cdc5b5cf478b9310b8503360969bbca4b89cb4d599683923aebc8c2c7
   Creation Time: Sun Apr 07 19:19:25 UTC 2019
   Bit Strength: 4096
   Has Revocation: false
   Has EncryptionKey: true
   Has MasterKey: false
Signature Packet
   Hash Algo: SHA256
   Version: Ver 4 (New)
   Key ID: 25e3b7a45660875
   Signature Type : Subkey Binding Signature (0x18)
```

Comment: Were you trying to import it as root or something?

Comment: no, i was i was just trying to use pgp public key to message someone, then after i used it it was flagged as doing something to the root in other program..

Comment: It would help enormously if you posted the exact message you received.